# Does division by 0 really have anything to do with $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, limits, solution-verification, field-theory

To my very limited knowledge, division by 0 is undefined precisely because it breaks the field axioms. No dividing by 0 if you want a field. However there do exist structures that are not fields which allow for division by 0. Like the Riemann sphere. Or wheel algebras.

However a very common argument/"proof" I often hear for why division by 0 is undefined, is that $\lim_{x \to 0+} \frac{1}{x} = \infty$ whereas $\lim_{x \to 0-} \frac{1}{x} = -\infty$. And therefore since the limits go the opposite direction, this means we can't say $\frac{1}{0} = \infty$.

But I do not understand this line of reasoning. If the left and right limits differ, that would just mean the limit from both sides isn't defined. It wouldn't tell me anything about the function's value *at* 0, only *near* 0? And I don't see why a function's behaviour near 0 would have anything to do with it's value at 0.

Is there a missing step? Or is it just a fallacy?

Edit: A few people just agreeing with me haha, so let me try put it another way. Is there anything, anything at all, that we can conclude about division by 0, specifically from the differing left/right limits of $\frac{1}{x}$?

Comment: I agree. The limit argument shows only that the function $1/x$ cannot be continuous at zero.

Comment: As you pointed out, the limit argument cannot be a direct reason for the impossibility of division-by-zero. (These two problems, however, can be related to each other in a topological field.)

Comment: @DavidK It's interesting, wikipedia gives the "proof" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero#Analysis). Maybe there is some kind of intuition behind it?

Comment: @SangchulLee Thanks! Could you elaborate a little on how the two problems can be related in topology?

Comment: That particular part of that page shows how various "limit" methods cannot define $1/0.$ The argument is very specific to that particular type of definition. It certainly does say something about division by zero namely, "You can't define division by zero that way." This is significant, because it is intuitively tempting to try to make such a definition.

Comment: @DavidK I don't see how one could "define division by 0" that way in the first place. I mean let's pretend the left and right limits were both positive infinity. Then we could say the general limit is also positive infinity. But how would that allow us to say 1/0 = infinity? Unless you mean to define 1/0 as the limit itself, in which case it's not really an algebraic object at all, as infinity isn't a number in this context. On the other hand, with something like the Riemann sphere, infinity is a number. And 1/0 = infinity. No limits needed. So what's the relation between 1/0 and the limit?

Comment: It's not a good definition, that's for sure. Instead of "intuitively tempting", perhaps I should have said "naïvely tempting". It's a definition sometimes put forward by people who haven't thought about it very deeply.

Comment: @DavidK Thank you